# How to set new files permission as its parent folder in hdfs?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

There is a folder **mydir** with 777 permission to its subdir and files.
I have to run chmod -R 777 /mydir every time when new files added in this folder.

So I tried with many commands like:-

**hadoop fs -chmod -R ugo+rwx /mydir** Does not change anything

**hadoop fs -ll -d /mydir** and **hadoop fs ll -d /mydir** Both result unknown command

**hadoop fs -tune2fs -l /mydir | grep "Default mount options:"** Again getting unknown command

**hadoop fs -setfacl -m "u:hadoop:rwx" /mydir** Invalid type of acl in  :u:hadoop:rwx (Here hadoop is username)

Is there any other command that can I try or is there any other way to run the above commands successfully?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this in Hadoop.  While UNIX/Linux has a umask setting per user, there is no equivalent in HDFS. If you are the Hadoop admin you can alter the umask property globally, however, not on a per user basis.

http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsPermissionsGuide.html